# Datatable remove specific div from row during export to csv

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, datatable

Please check below table for what I want in export to `csv`.
I have used `Datatable`. I want to remove / hide `removeit` class and its content during export to `csv`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John doe <div class="removeit">Remove this content</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here, I found solution by myself.    
buttons: [ 
                { 
                    extend: 'csvHtml5', 
                    text: 'Export to Csv',
                    exportOptions: {
                      format: {
                            body: function ( data, row, column, node, type ) {
                               if(column==0){
                                   var lines = data.split('<div');
                                  var count_d = 0;
                                   jQuery.each(lines, function() {
                                        if(count_d==0){
                                            data = this;
                                        }
                                        count_d++;
                                    });
                               }
                               else{
                                   data = data;
                               }
                              return data; 

                            }
                        }    
                    }
                } 
            ],
```